# Replacing only the alphabetical letters in a string

Tags: python, string, replace

I need to return the given puzzle with each alphabetic character replaced by the HIDDEN character.

```
HIDDEN = '^' 

def blah(r):
    r = HIDDEN * len(r)
    return r
```

This function works for replacing any string I need, but the question specifically asks that each ALPHABETIC character be replaced.

So I can't have `4` or `'` or `?` being replaced with HIDDEN because they're not alphabetic characters.

How should I go about this?

Comment: @sberry: the homework tag has been [deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: So, how would you determine what characters are alpha characters?  Surely you know some way to do this?  Loop through all letters?  Regex? Filter?  Do something to show an attempt and perhaps we can help you `refine` your code then.

Comment: @DSM, and replaced?  I hope...

Comment: Looks rather similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/12965551/21945

Comment: @mhawke: They must be in the same class.

Comment: That link is most likely someone in my class, yes. I actually haven't learned any Regex, Filter or any of that. I'm at a very very basic beginner level.

Comment: @sberry Not replaced. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One approach: use the *translate* method:

```
import string

table = string.maketrans(string.ascii_letters, '^'*len(string.ascii_letters))

def blah(r):
    return r.translate(table)
```

Another approach: use `re.sub`:

```
import re

def blah(r):
    return re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z]', r'^', r)
```

Comment: While this is a completely suitable answer, we should expect a little more from the OP in terms of effort.

Comment: For the sake of future visitors, I like giving complete answers. I'm torn between supporting pedagogy and supporting the intent of SO...

Comment: Point made.  It sucks that it has to turn into this though.

Comment: def blah(r):
 import re
 return re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z]',HIDDEN, r)
i changed it slightly into that^^ because i think a part of the assignment is the idea of calling the HIDDEN preset given by the teacher within the function
The testing worked out fine for that, so that should work well right?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [maketrans](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.maketrans), you can create a translation table from `string.letters` to `^` and then use it.

Answer (score 1):

I've always found `maketrans` to be a little difficult to understand, so I usually fall back on more primitive ways of doing these things (which make more sense to me):

```
def make_hidden(instr):
    return ''.join(c if c.isalpha() else '^' for c in instr)
```

Comment: `c if c.isalpha() else '^'` might be cleaner; then you don't need `string.ascii_letters` at all.

Comment: @nneonneo -- Excellent point!  (+1 for your comment and your original answer)

Answer (score 1):

Return the given puzzle with each alphabetic character replaced by the HIDDEN character.

```
HIDDEN = '^' 

def blah(r):

    new_r = ""

    for ch in r:

        if ch in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ':

           new_r += HIDDEN 

        else:

           new_r += ch

     return new_r
```